# How to handle the click of a cell in a FlexTable?

Tags: gwt, onclick

I have a FlexTable in GWT, and I would like an event to happen at the click of a single cell or in a group of cells. Can it be done?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the simplest solution

```
new ClickHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        int cellIndex = flexTable.getCellForEvent(event).getCellIndex();
        int rowIndex = flexTable.getCellForEvent(event).getRowIndex();
    }
};
```

Comment: Also don't forget to check for null returned from getCellForEvent(event) method before calling getRowIndex() or getCellIndex()

Comment: If there is an event on table it can't be null

Comment: getCellForEvent will return null in case you have set cellSpacing and you click into area of cell spacing! Tested it in GWT 2.7.0